# Problems in hosting multiple Django cms projects under the same domain?

Tags: apache, cpanel, mod-wsgi, django-cms

I am a beginner, I do want to deploy multiple Django cms projects under the same domain. I achieved it by using apache 2.2 and mod_wsgi 4.5.3 the configuration is below.

```
ServerName example.com
WSGIDaemonProcess blog python-home=/home/rndbkw/project/virtualenv2.7 python-path=/home/rndbkw/project/djangocms
WSGIScriptAlias /blog /home/rndbkw/project/djangocms/rnd/wsgi.py process-group=blog application-group=%{GLOBAL}

WSGIDaemonProcess rnd python-home=/home/rndbkw/virtualenv2.7 python-path=/home/rndbkw/djangocms
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/rndbkw/djangocms/rnd/wsgi.py process-group=rnd application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

But i am facing multiple issues now, When i am login to the first site it will be working fine without any hassles. Then i am login to the example.com/blog after login it will be redirecting to the example.com and another issue i found that when i am removing the configuration for example.com(root) then i looking example.com/blog the style(css) of the page will be lost. Any solutions will be appreciated...

Comment: Are you setting ``SESSION_COOKIE_PATH`` for each site differently? See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#session-cookie-path

Comment: Also look at login/logout settings as these do not from memory get automatically prefixed with the mount point of the site. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url