# Deploying django and django cms under one domain?

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, django-cms

I am a beginner i need to host multiple Django and django cms under one domain
i am using mod_wsgi handler for hosting. I used to follow the following configuration.

```
ServerName example.tk

WSGIDaemonProcess blog python-home=/home/nidhinjames/djangosite/virtualenv3.5 python-path=/home/nidhinjames/djangosite/mysite
WSGIScriptAlias /djangosite /home/nidhinjames/djangosite/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py process-group=blog application-group=%{GLOBAL}

WSGIDaemonProcess rnd python-home=/home/nidhinjames/djangocms/virtualenv3.5 python-path=/home/nidhinjames/djangocms/september
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/nidhinjames/djangocms/september/september/wsgi.py process-group=rnd application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

when i calling example.tk it will render my djangocms site properly but example.tk/djanosite showing 404 not found.
Any solutions can be appreciated.

Comment: Have you followed the Django documentation for how to collect together your static files and then configured Django as to what URL they should be found at, and then configured mod_wsgi to host the static files at that URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems in hosting multiple Django cms projects under the same domain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39782836/problems-in-hosting-multiple-django-cms-projects-under-the-same-domain)